# Javascript callback function and an argument in the callback. How must it be used based on the code snippet provided?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading over a legacy codebase and I ran into this following code:

```
andThenWe: function(callback) {
      var qunitAssertAsync = new window.AssertAsync(callback);

      return qunitAssertAsync;
    },
```

and here's the call site:

```
  andThenWe(function(done) {
    ...(some code)
    done();
  });
```

So in the call site, we're passing in an anonymous function which will then be === 'callback' right? However, this callback has an argument called done and seems to be called at the end of this function. That argument is kind of like a block parameter in Ruby right? So somewhere in the `window.assertAsync` the callback MUST be called and passed some kind of arugment which is probably === to Qunit's `assert.async` right? (most likely). The details of the `window.assertAsync` are really complicated so I just want to understand at a high level what must be going on. Am I making proper assumptions?

This is all possible because `callback` in the function signature is an anonymous function that be invoked at a later time right? Also `done` itself in the callback function must be a function itself at runtime right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an attempt to make `qunit.async` more "readable" (haha).

`qunit.async` is used to force tests to wait until an async operation has completed before exiting the test.

The `done` callback must be invoked when the writer of the test knows everything async has completed.